# How to focus jQuery's Selectmenu widget to emulate native select

Tags: jquery, focus, jquery-ui-selectmenu

My question is about the following page:

http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/ (jQuery's Selectmenu Widget API documentation)

It states near the top:

> ### Keyboard interaction
>
> When the menu is open, the following key commands are available:
>
> - `UP`/`LEFT`: Move focus to the previous item.
> - `DOWN`/`RIGHT`: Move focus to the next item.
>
> etc.

However, the three examples they give at the bottom of the page (as well as my own code) show that keyboard interaction does not happen by default. You have to explicitly tab to the control before the keyboard can be used with them, otherwise pressing `UP` or `DOWN` scrolls the whole page instead. I have tested this with Opera (Presto), Firefox 32 and Opera 24 (Chrome/Webkit) and got the same behaviour on all of them.

How can I completely emulate the native behaviour of `<select>`s? Is `onclick` enough or are there other events I haven't thought of that cause an input to receive focus (as I said previously, tab already works)?

Answer (score 4):

You can focus the selectmenu by focusing the menu button:

If your selectmenu id is #myDropDown you can focus the menu like this:

```
$('#myDropDown-button').focus();
```